# need surface plot of my graph or bar should be coloured acc to height

Tags: graph, 3d

x_pred = (Net_Out(1,:))';
y_pred = (Net_Out(2,:))';

x_true = correct_output(:,1);
y_true = correct_output(:,2);

err = sqrt((x_pred - x_true).^2 + (y_pred - y_true).^2);

figure
stem3(x_true, y_true, err,'Marker','none', 'LineWidth', 2)

want to add color to bars according to the error height.
or
if surface plot can be generated from this, that would be helpful too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oekQI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want a surface plot for error